# Force react component to re-render after state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have below JSX, which is a popover inside Box. `isActive` is a prop taken by Popover which keeps the Popover open. Now on click event i am trying to update the value of `isActive` to keep it open but it's not happening. How to correct it?

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
<Box variant="light">
  <Popover
    id="myPopover"
    isActive={open}
    items={[
      {
        children: <Type weight="semibold">Popover Item</Type>
      },
      {
        children: <Type weight="semibold">Popover Item</Type>
      },
      {
        children: <Type weight="semibold">Popover Item</Type>,
        disabled: true
      },
      {
        children: <Type weight="semibold">Click Me</Type>,
        onClick: event => {
          console.log('Clicked', event);
          setOpen(true);
          
        }
      }
    ]}
    
  >
    <div>My Popover</div>
  </Popover>
</Box>;
```

Comment: `isActive={open}`? And you should have `onClose` event to set the state to false too.

Comment: @DennisVash How can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean? Use the state instead of hardcoding `isActive`

Comment: @DennisVash My bad, i have updated the code in post, I am setting `isActive` from state but Popover is closing.

Comment: can share whats the implementation of Popover ? to understand whats on onClick event is attached to

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I need to get the value of PopOver items on click without closing the same. Currently, with each item click, Popover is getting closed which i am trying to stop.

Comment: is Popover your custom code ? or using third party package? trying to understand the api used in the popover to handle `isActive`..

Comment: It's a third party implementation @MurtazaHussain

Comment: can you please share the popover code in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi isActive is always false in your code. You should set `isActive={open}`

Try this esxample

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const Example = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const togglePopover = useCallback(() => {
    setOpen=((prev) => !prev)
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <Box variant="light">
      <Popover
        id="myPopover"
        isActive={open}
        items={[
          {
            children: <Type weight="semibold">Popover Item</Type>
          },
          {
            children: <Type weight="semibold">Popover Item</Type>
          },
          {
            children: <Type weight="semibold">Popover Item</Type>,
            disabled: true
          },
          {
            children: <Type weight="semibold">Click Me</Type>,
            onClick: togglePopover
          }
        ]}

      >
        <div>My Popover</div>
      </Popover>
    </Box>;
  );
}
```

Comment: Getting 'setOpen' is readonly error at  setOpen=((prev) => !prev).

Comment: Typo in the answer. It should be `setOpen((prev) => !prev)`

Answer (score 0):

onClick function should switch the `open` state from true to false and vice versa.
fix your onclick function to be as follow

```
setOpen(!open);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Button from './button';

const App = () => {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const onClick = useCallback((e) => {
setOpen((prev) => !prev);
}, []);
 return (
  <div>
  {open && <div>show value of open: {open ? 'true' : 'false'} 
  </div>}
  <br/>
  <Button callbackClick={onClick} />
  </div>
  );};
```